# Adjective or Adverb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

When someone asks "How are you doing?". Is it:

> 1. I am doing bad.
> 2. I am doing badly.

Though I always hear the first one, *I think* the second is more correct because here, doing acts as a verb(present progressive) so we should use the adverb(badly) to modify it.

I would like to ask which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

The correct positive response to "how are you doing" is "I am doing well". Often people will say "I'm good", which is idiomatic but probably not strictly speaking grammatical.

The negative response, then, would be "I am doing badly". Contrary to U11-Forward's answer, this is perfectly correct and understandable.

"I'm doing good" has quite a different connotation; it means you are performing positive actions, such as helping people or giving to charity. I don't think you would ever say "I'm doing bad", but if you did it would imply you were doing things that hurt people.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct.

It says "I am doing bad". When you feel good you would say "I am doing good", it's an exact opposite of "I am doing bad".

Saying "I am doing badly" would sound strange. As the mentioned in the Dictionary, the meaning of "badly" is:

> in an unsatisfactory, inadequate, or unsuccessful way.

And the example sentence is:

> "England have played badly this year"

"badly" would be mentioning that something is going badly.

You wouldn't here anyone say "I am doing goodly" as well.

If you want to say something with "badly", it would be something like:

> It is going badly.

Comment: You wouldn't say "doing goodly" because the adverb from "good" is "well".

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's true